# Don't refresh when typing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, refresh, typing

This is my code:

```
// Refresh feeds, but ONLY when you are NOT typing
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#load-feeds").load('/actions/loadfeed.php?randval='+ Math.random());
}, 9000);
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

I'm working on a kind of "wall" like Facebook where you can comment on each other's posts. The wall automatically refreshes with AJAX (every 9 seconds), but when you're typing and the textfield is focused it removes the focus and the content of the textbox after the page refreshed.

How can I make it only refresh when you're NOT typing and make it stop when you're typing. Thanks! I've looked everywhere and tried everything, but no luck.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but shouldn't the cache false be unnecessary given that you have a random query param?

Comment: Just to make sure, but I haven't tested without caching off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have an input box like this:

```
<input type="text" id="input-box" ... />
```

All you have to do is mantain a global variable than says if this input has the focus:

```
var isTyping = false;
$("#input-box").focus(function() {
    isTyping = true;
});
$("#input-box").blur(function() {
    isTyping = false;
});
```

then you just have to check this variable before to allow the update:

```
// Refresh feeds, but ONLY when you are NOT typing
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    if (!isTyping) {
        $("#load-feeds").load('/actions/loadfeed.php?randval='+ Math.random());
}, 9000);
    }
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Comment: This will probably work but how can I have it to check all input boxes? Or at least input boxes with the same class? I have multiple text boxes.

Comment: Change the $("#input-box") to.. $(".class-name") or a list of classes $("#input-box1, #input-box2, #input-box3")

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a `timeout` timer running when they type, and check before you load:

```
var typing = false,
    theTimer,
    refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        typing || $("#load-feeds").load('/actions/loadfeed.php?randval='+ Math.random());
    }, 9000);
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

$('#theInput').keyup(function() {
    typing = true;
    theTimer && clearTimeout(theTimer);

    theTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        typing = true;
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: That's how you declare multiple variables with the same `var` keyword: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch04_02.htm